# Extend aws firehose stream buffering period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Can I somehow extend the duration of the firehose stream buffering interval to be more than 900 seconds? I'm working with small files sized ~100kb after 15 min of streaming to s3. I need extended buffering interval or another way to merge 4 files every hour and what is the best way to do that?

I don't want to download these files and then do merging because of many firehose streams, so only direct solution on AWS would be considered.

I've read so many things linked to this problem, and I couldn't find any useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 900s (15 minutes) is a hard limit on the amount of time Kinesis will wait to buffer.

However, if your data is moving this slowly then you can handle your hourly merge yourself.

An approach to this would to be to use a lambda function that was scheduled to invoke every hour, listed the files in the target bucket(s), read them, merged them, wrote them into a "merged" bucket/prefix and then deleted the merged files.

Alternatively you could have a lambda trigger on the S3 fire-hose bucket invoked whenever a file is written. This trigger would read all the files in that bucket, and merge them. It has the advantage that you merge your buckets in parallel and will not have to wait an hour for your file to be combined.

(You should note that S3 is not consistent at fast write speeds or when listing large numbers of files, so this is not a good solution if your data speed increases to the point where you're writing multiple files a minute.)